# Sharing to Instagram in ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7

So I used to have the following snippet of code for iOS6

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:originalImagePath];

    self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageURL];
    self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
    self.documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    [self.documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

but with the release of iOS7 once I get the dialog window that shows the Instagram icon with **Open in Instagram** I'm getting the following error:

`Invalid LSOpenOperation request - No applications found to open document`

Does anyone know if Instagram has changed their `UTI` for iOS7 or what is the appropriate developer hooks to make it work on 7?

Comment: Did you check the docs on Instagrams developer site?

Comment: I tried the iphone hooks they have on documentation http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/#

Comment: And you read the document interaction section which tells you about file naming and UTI?

Comment: Yes, currently changing my file extension to .ig just to be sure this is not the culprit....

Comment: And the File Extension was my culprit! Renamed and Done!

Comment: When I click on "Open In Instagram" then it dismiss the dialog and nothing happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My file extension was the culprit.

As per Instagram Docs:

> You must first save your file in PNG or JPEG (preferred) format and use the filename extension ".ig". Using the iOS Document Interaction APIs you can trigger the photo to be opened by Instagram.

Looks like the older version of instagram it was not enforced (I was getting away with just passing .jpg or .png files)

Now we **must** have the **.ig** file extension...

Answer (score 2):

Use the UIActivity designed for Instagram and add to your UIActivityViewController code.

See; https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dmactivityinstagram

I use it in all my apps and it works great!